# How to match a substring and convert it to a hyperlink?

Tags: php, html, regex, string, preg-replace

I need help with my application. I want to match a substring with a regex expression and then extract it. There is my code:

```
$text = getTranslation('end_date', $translation);
if (strstr($text, "/@:url[.*?]/")){
    $text = str_replace("/@:url[.*?]/", "<a href='$promo->wabsiteUrl'>ANYTHING</a>", $text);
}
echo $text;
```

`getTranslation()` is a method that I created to get the translation item `end_date` in my object `$translation`. The problem is that I'm pretty bad with regex. I tried something, and it does not work.

Here's what the variable `$text` is: `@:url[Click here] to find out where to buy Razer inc.` (Coming from `$translation`)

`@:url` is equal to my promotion website and then what's inside the `[]` is the text for my `<a href=""></a>` element.

So, I need to look for `@:url[ANYTHING]` and then extract the `ANYTHING` to create this `<a href="">ANYTHING</a>`

Comment: Never use `strstr()` to check the existence of a substring, use `strpos()` because it is more efficient.  The manual advises this: `Note #2` @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: ... of course if you are using `preg_replace()` there is no reason to check for the existence of the substring first -- the function simply won't replace anything if the substring is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit lost so here's what I understand:

```
preg_replace("#/@:(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/#", "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>", $text);
```

This will match strings of the form `/@:<something>[anotherthing]/` and replace them with `<a href="something">anotherthing</a>`

Update:

```
preg_replace("#/@:url\[(.*?)\]/#", "<a href=\"".$promo->websiteUrl."\">$1</a>", $text);
```

This will match strings of the form `/@:url[thing]/` and replace them with `<a href="your promo url in that variable">thing</a>`

If you don't need the `//` then you can change the regex to `"#@:url\[(.*?)\]#"`

Comment: You are pretty close, ```@:url``` is just a static variable to tell me that I will do an  ```<a href=""></a>``` in my code. It tell me that I need to put ```$promo->websiteUrl``` in the ```href``` attribute too. So I do not need to extract it. But, I do need to extract the text between these character [] then place it in the ```<a></a>``` attribute. In conclusion, $1 is not good but $2 is the good one.

Comment: @Devoplex I've updated the answer. Check the updated segment.

Comment: Wow, that work! Thanks alot. But do you have an idea what I should write in my ```if``` condition? That's the only thing that do not work there...

Comment: if you must have an if (which you don't really need) it could be `if (strstr($text, "@:url")`

Comment: Thanks you, I only did a ```preg_match("#@:url\[(.*?)\]#", $text)``` and it worked very well.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this ?

```
if(preg_match_all('%@:url\[(.*?)\]%i', $text, $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: As I said to bellow, I need to extract the value between [ ] and then put it where you wrote HEY.

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you try this ? You will see that you want data in print_r() function.

Comment: I tried and it work pretty well too,  but I do prefer the answer of @apokryfos.